# Erro ao pegar variável de retorno do webservice

Tags: c#, web-service

Eu tenho uma variável que eu retorno que é do tipo `x509Certificate2`, porém ao ter o retorno no sistema, ela sempre vem null, porém do webserver, ele retorna perfeitamente, não estou sabendo como converter. 
Criei uma `class` com o mesmo nome, e mesmo variável, e faço assim:

```
 ResultadoCert a = new ResultadoCert(); 
                    a.Certificado = (await client.CertificadoAsync(item.Serial));
```

Ele retorna o seguinte erro:

> Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo
>   "ServiceReference1.ResultadoCert" em
>   "System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2"

Como posso corrigir? Já tentei receber na var, e passar para `x509Certificate2` porém ele vem `null`

**EDIT**

Essa é a `class` para receber, mudei um pouco agora:

```
public class ResultadoCert {
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public X509Certificate2 Certificado { get; set; }
}
```

E aqui é o que eu retorno do `webservice`

```
 public ResultadoCert Certificado(string serial)
    {
        ResultadoCert resultado = new ResultadoCert();
        X509Certificate2Collection collection = Certificados.SelecionarCertificado(serial);

        if (collection.Count == 1)
        {
            resultado.Certificado = collection[0];
            resultado.Result = true;
            return resultado;
        }
        else { resultado.Result = false; resultado.Certificado = null; return resultado; }
    }
```

Aqui é como estou tentando receber:

```
 ResultadoCert a = new ResultadoCert();
                    var cert = await client.CertificadoAsync(item.Serial);
                    if (cert.Result)
                    {
                        a.Certificado = cert.Certificado;
                        //a.Certificado = client.CertificadoAsync(item.Serial).Result.Certificado;
                    }
```

Depurando no webservice, ele retorna corretamente, porém quando vou passar o retorno que estou tendo problemas.

Comment: eu não sei como está o seu código, mas poderia verificar duas coisa ?

1º - Certifique-se que você está no **Client** correto, imagino que já deva ter feito isso mil vezes, mas só para confirmar.

2º - Certifique-se que o retorno do seu método é um **Task<x509Certificate2>**, para métodos **Async** precisamos colocar isso no retorno para que ele possa vir corretamente.

Se você puder mostrar todo o código para nós, o seu método, a sua classe, o tipo, e principalmente o retorno, ajudaria bastante a comunidade a te ajudar.

Comment: @RichardWillian editei a pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

@marianac_costa, ali no seu **Retorno do Web Service**, vê que o seu **retorno** é **ResultadoCert** então, não teria como você atribuir diretamente ao seu objeto `a.Certificado`, porque é o mesmo que você forçar o seu `Certificado` virar um `ResultadoCert`.

Para corrigir isso, você deveria trocar o **Retorno** do seu método no `Service`, ou retornar o **ResultadoCert** mesmo. Ficaria assim:

### Retornando ResultadoCert

```
public Task<ResultadoCert> Certificado(string serial)
{
        ResultadoCert resultado = new ResultadoCert();
        X509Certificate2Collection collection = 
        Certificados.SelecionarCertificado(serial);

        if (collection.Count == 1)
        {
            resultado.Certificado = collection[0];
            resultado.Result = true;
            return resultado;
        }
        else 
        { 
          resultado.Result = false; resultado.Certificado = null; 
          return resultado; 
        }
}
```

**Obs:** Note que eu adicionei o `Task<Objeto>`, isso resolveria o problema de estar retornando `null`quando a variável é do tipo `var`(que você havia comentado).

### Chamada do Service (Retornando ResultadoCert)

```
ResultadoCert a = new ResultadoCert();
var resultadoCertoRetornado = await client.CertificadoAsync(item.Serial);
if (resultadoCertoRetornado.Certificado.Result)
{
    a.Certificado = await resultadoCertoRetornado.Certificado;
}
```

### Retornando Certificado

```
public Task<Certificado> Certificado(string serial)
    {
            ResultadoCert resultado = new ResultadoCert();
            X509Certificate2Collection collection = 
            Certificados.SelecionarCertificado(serial);

            if (collection.Count == 1)
            {
                return collection[0];
            }
            else 
            { 
              return null; 
            }
    }
```

### Chamada do Service (Retornando Certificado)

```
ResultadoCert a = new ResultadoCert();

var certificadoRetornadaService = await client.CertificadoAsync(item.Serial);
if (certificadoRetornadaService.IsNotNull())
{
        a.Certificado = await certificadoRetornadaService;
}
```

Comment: Ele está me retornando o seguinte erro em resultado.  Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo "WSModuloSeg.Uteis.ResultadoCert" em "System.Threading.Tasks.Task<WSModuloSeg.Uteis.ResultadoCert>"

Comment: @marianac_costa, N chamada do método, na atribuição ao objeto, coloca `await`, assim:
` a.Certificado = await certificadoRetornadaService;`

Vou atualizar a resposta.

Comment: Fiz desta maneira, ele nem entra no retorno do certificado, ele ja retorna o erro An exception was thrown while attempting to evaluate a LINQ query parameter expression. To show additional information call EnableSensitiveDataLogging() when overriding DbContext.OnConfiguring. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at lambda_method(Closure )

Comment: E eu tenho um método antes, que o retorno funciona, deste que dá erro.

Comment: Poxa, eu não estou entendendo então, tipo, o seu problema inicial, era só porque no seu método, estava retornando `ResultadoCert` e você estava atribuindo a um `Certificado`. O mesmo de tentar atribuir um `int` em um `string`. Mas ai você disse que colocou `var` para retornar qualquer coisa, e vinha `null`. E o `Task<>`era para resolver isso.

Estranho, não sei o que pode ser, desculpa @marianac_costa

Comment: No webservice ele retorna normal, não ocorre erro, e no breakpoint, deu p ver que está pegando certo, e no sistema, ele retorna erro ao serializar, já tentei várias formas, porém nenhum da certo.

Comment: Você não tem nenhum outro método que funciona e consiga retornar ? Porque agora analisando sua classe, eu não vi o `DataAnnotation` `[Serializable]`, não precisa ? Ou você só não ta mostrando ali na sua pergunta ?

Comment: É porque já tentei colocar porém também não resolveu, então fiz o teste sem

Comment: Esse método aqui, `Certificados.SelecionarCertificado(serial);` faz uma consulta no banco? É que você disse que está retornando os dados corretamente, mas esse tipo de problema de `DbContext`está relacionado com `Entity Framework`, `ORM`, etc.

Se puder confirmar, mas como você já disse, debugando você já viu que está funcionando normal o `WebService`, então é só uma dúvida de desencargo da consciência.

Comment: Não, ele retorna os certificados na máquina, uso o mesmo método p assinar e funciona, somente neste quando eu só busco e preciso retornar o certificado que não funciona

Comment: Descobri que o problema ta ao passar a variavel x509Certificate2, ao passar só outra comum, deu certo, só a do certificado que não.

Comment: Boa, que bom que conseguiu, e qual é o problema dessa Classe `x509Certificate2`, você saberia dizer ? Estou curioso agora.

Comment: Ainda não descobri, rs estou tentando ver o que pode ser, o porque que ele não recebe os dados dela, sendo que o tipo é o mesmo.

Comment: @marianac_costa, quando você mudou o tipo da propriedade, você retirou o `[IgnoreDataMember]`de cima da propriedade ? Testa da próxima vez, com o `[DataMember]` e utiliza a sua classe `x509Certificate2`.

Comment: Já tentei e mesmo assim não deu, ao pesquisar vi que é de um tipo complexo, porém se o retorno é do mesmo tipo, deveria passar sem problemas.

Comment: Eu não consegui retornar o `type` `x509Certificate2`, para não perder muito tempo tive que mudar a parte onde recebia ele, para não precisar ser passado. Se futuramente encontrar alguma alternativa eu volto para responder. Obrigado pela ajuda Richard.

Comment: Não consegui ajudar muito, mas de nada kkk. Só gostaria de pedir para você colocar essa `classe` aqui nos comentários para eu dar uma olhada nela ? Tentar colocar ela inteira, se possível. E se você futuramente achar a resposta, por favor, diga pra gente, porque essa foi complicada kkkk